# x2darray.mount systemd automount unit

Tags: ubuntu, mount, systemd, fstab

I am trying to develop a better understanding of how luks [auto]decrypting and fs [auto]mounting operate under systemD, based on observations as I work through some issues setting up a replacement devbox; vanilla ubuntu 20.04, and relevant to this question has an (existing) btrfs disk array; 3 hdd's in raid1.

I noticed the following unit

`mnt-data\x2darray.mount    loaded active     mounted   /mnt/data-array`

I have the following `crypttab` and `fstab` entries:

`data_array_disk1 /dev/disk/by-uuid/[uuid] /[keyfile]`

`/dev/mapper/data_array_disk1 /mnt/data-array defaults,subvol=/ 0 2`

I can see from the `systemd.mount` manpage how the `mnt-data.*` name is likely formed, but the manpage (and google) have *nothing* for `x2darray.mount` The name sounds like it may be related to creating one mountpoint from an array of disks ... but nothing piques the curiosity like zero google results.

What is this `x2darray.mount`?

Answer (score 0):

well, sometimes posting the question clarifies things ...

`\` != `/` obviously, but I misread the slash.

`\x2d` == `-` encoded.

So, nevermind, `data\x2darray` is just `data-array` :)